# react-native counter, function is undefined

Tags: react-native

I've slightly changed the default App.js from react native's quick start guide, I tried to make a counter that would count up from 1 every time I hit the button in the middle of the screen. When I run the following code, I get this error: `Warning: Failed prop type: The prop 'onPress' is marked as required in 'Button', but its value is 'undefined'....` The problem is that it doesn't recognize `this.onButtonPress()` inside the function `renderButton = () => {}`. I think it may be a problem with the keyword `this`, because I've heard that that points to the parent function and not the parent object, but I believe this should still work... I'm not sure why it doesn't. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Button
} from 'react-native';

const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' +
    'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android: 'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 1
    };
  }

  renderButton = () => {
    return(
      <Button
        onPress={this.onButtonPress()}
        title="BUTTON"
        color="#841584"
      />
    );
  }

  onButtonPress = () => {
    var previous = this.state.count;
    this.state.count = previous + 1;
  }
  
  render = () => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.renderButton()}
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Count: {this.state.count}
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          To get started, edit App.js
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          {instructions}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

[image: image of warning message and screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were invoking the function instead of passing the reference.

```
renderButton = () => {
    return(
        <Button
            onPress={this.onButtonPress} // <-- you were invoking the function here instead of passing the reference
            title="BUTTON"
            color="#841584"
        />
    );
}
```

Alternatively, you could pass an anonymous function that calls your method.

```
renderButton = () => {
    return(
        <Button
            onPress={() => this.onButtonPress()}
            title="BUTTON"
            color="#841584"
        />
    );
}
```

The reason React thought it was `undefined` is because the function execution didn't have a return value and was therefore returning `undefined`. Your function ran immediately instead of after the `onPress` event. So React used the result of the function as the `onPress` event handler instead of the function itself.

Answer (score 1):

When updating state in React, you want to use setState. Below is an example using your code:

```
onButtonPress = () => {
    var newCount = this.state.count + 1;
     this.setState({
      count: newCount
    });
  }
```

Comment: Yeah, that too. But that wasn't causing his error. :)